# Extract arguments from string pattern

Tags: java, json, matcher

I have a String pattern like this

```
String pattern = "Send {{message}} to {{name}}";
```

Than I have  a sentence like this one

```
String sentence = "Send Hi there to Jesus";
```

What I want is to match sentences with a pattern and return something like a 
JsonObject that has the arguments from the sentence:

```
{"message": "Hi there", "name": "Jesus"}
```

Are there any simple solutions for this ?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with Regex then there's [`MessageFormat.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)). However, I would use [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). `Send\\s+(?<message>.*?)\\s+to\\s+(?<name>.*)` ought to do it.

Comment: Edited the question tags. The design pattern tag is misplaced here. Please read the description of the tag.

Comment: `MessageFormat.parse` is the other way around of what I want. I'm not very familiar with regex, any hints ?

Comment: @BoristheSpider The regex doesn't seem to match..

Comment: Boris used "<>" instead of "{{}}" - is it that?

Comment: @Fildor it doesn't matter. I used his pattern with the sentence and it didn't match anything.

Comment: It is making use of (named) groups. So I was actually wrong: the <> belong to the syntax of the named group definition. Can you show the code you tried?

Comment: See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html and this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group-java.lang.String-

Comment: If the sentence is `Send Not to me to Peter`, do you want `{"message": "Not", "name": "me to Peter"}` or `{"message": "Not to me", "name": "Peter"}`? Dare you assume name does not contain `to` as a separate word?

Comment: @OleV.V. First "to" is considered to be part of the pattern. So `{..."name": "me to Peter"}`.

Comment: @Fildor I have not tried it in java yet, only in an online regex parser.. will let you know as soon as I figure out how to use it.

Comment: @OP works fine - [see it in action](https://regex101.com/r/9ln6zr/2). Although as [Ove V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569731/extract-arguments-from-string-pattern/41570193#comment70344559_41569731) points out, the first group needs to be greedy.

Comment: @BoristheSpider if you want to split at the first “to” (as I understood the asker’s comment), it exactly needs to be reluctant. Otherwise fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. yeah, indeed unclear. Greedy seems to make a little more sense as then we only leave the last "to". Who knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This unit test extracts the sentence content by refererencing matched groups (note the enclosing round brackets) via the group index. If the pattern matches the given string, then the entire input string is group 0. In the given example, the matched `message` is at group index 1 and the `name` at index 2. Alternatively, you can define named groups.

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class Snippet {

    private final String testSentence;
    private final String[][] expectedResult;



    public Snippet(String testSentence, String[][] expectedMessages) {
        this.testSentence = testSentence;
        this.expectedResult = expectedMessages;
    }

    private String[][] extractSentenceContent(String sentence) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Send\\s([\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)\\sto\\s([\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);

        String[][] result;

        if(matcher.matches()) {
            result = new String[][] {{"message", matcher.group(1)}, {"name", matcher.group(2)}};
        } else {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegex(){

        String[][] actualResult = extractSentenceContent(testSentence);

        TestCase.assertTrue(Arrays.deepEquals(expectedResult, actualResult));
    }



    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<?> getTestParameters(){

        Object[][] parameters = {
                {"Send Hi there to Jesus", new String[][] {{"message", "Hi there"}, {"name", "Jesus"}}}
        };
        return Arrays.asList(parameters);
    }
}
```

> Is there any way to get the capturing group name from the template,
>   without hardcoding "message" and "name" ?

An ad-hoc solution could be to use [String.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) to insert dynamic capture group names like this:

```
private String[][] extractSentenceContent(String sentence, String captureGroupA, String captureGroupB) {
    String pattern = String.format("^Send\\s(?<%s>[\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)\\sto\\s(?<%s>[\\p{Alpha}\\s]+)$", captureGroupA, captureGroupB);

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(sentence);

    String[][] result;

    if(matcher.matches()) {
        result = new String[][] {
            {captureGroupA, matcher.group(captureGroupA)}, 
            {captureGroupB, matcher.group(captureGroupB)}
        };
    } else {
        result = null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You don't need both anchors (`^` and `$`) and `matcher.matches`. +1 for the parameterised unit test - very good advice.

Comment: Is there any way to get the capturing group name from the template, without hardcoding "message" and "name" ?

Comment: @adi.neag that's what [my example](https://regex101.com/r/9ln6zr/2) does. I would strongly recommend against blindly copying Regex without comprehension however - it will come back to bite you when your requirements change.

Comment: @BoristheSpider What I wanted to say is a way to get the first String in the array of results without hardcoding it. Now, we have to hardcode it (`result = new String[][] {{"hardcoded", matcher.group(1)}..`.

Comment: @adi.neag and as I said, it codes the names of the groups into the pattern. Sadly there is no way, in the Java API, to get the names of matched groups.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ok, too bad. I wanted to have a generic method that takes in different patterns and sentences and outputs the results.

Comment: @adi.neag Please see the updated answer whether it's what you meant.

Comment: @SME_Dev yes, it's ok for now. Thanks for helping me guys :)

Answer (score -1):

```
i= sentence.length();

while(sentence[i] != " "){
    i--;
}

i++;

for(intj=0;j<i;j++)
    name[j]= sentence[j];
}

for(int k = 5;k<(sentence.length()-i-3);k++){
    message[k] = sentence[k];
}
```

Comment: Please format code you post. Please don't post code only answers.

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.